Why does memory usage grow until system fails? Cannot find the cause
When working in front of my computer, ram memory usage grows util filled up, apps start to close, and eventually the system freezes. This happens every 3~6 hours. The only solution I've found is either restart, or (surprisingly) stop using the computer. If I stand up and go do something else, memory usage goes down eventually.
Also, if I suspend my machine, it goes down back to normal.
I'm just using Chrome and terminal (several tabs and tmux sessions). I have 32GB of RAM. I think I shouldn't be having this kind of problems.
I've read about Linux memory usage and I think it does not apply, because applications are being shut down.
I cannot find a running application that is responsible for such amount of consumption. The app that is more demanding is Chrome, but when memory consumption is at 100% and the Linux out of memory killer terminates it, memory only drops to ~80%. Okey, chrome eats a lot, but it does not explain the memory eat up over time.
Some debug info when memory is at 93%
free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31968       30026         493       24044       25951        1941
Swap:           7627        7090         537

cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       32735472 kB
MemFree:          505772 kB
MemAvailable:    1988436 kB
Buffers:          172672 kB
Cached:         26087896 kB
SwapCached:        43056 kB
Active:         14243856 kB
Inactive:        9319232 kB
Active(anon):   13345184 kB
Inactive(anon):  8579644 kB
Active(file):     898672 kB
Inactive(file):   739588 kB
Unevictable:     7619516 kB
Mlocked:             232 kB
SwapTotal:       7811068 kB
SwapFree:         549920 kB
Zswap:                 0 kB
Zswapped:              0 kB
Dirty:             61452 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       4871864 kB
Mapped:           866112 kB
Shmem:          24622004 kB
KReclaimable:     313592 kB
Slab:             582740 kB
SReclaimable:     313592 kB
SUnreclaim:       269148 kB
KernelStack:       29212 kB
PageTables:       155060 kB
SecPageTables:         0 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    24178804 kB
Committed_AS:   78879912 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       76300 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             9632 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    892928 kB
ShmemHugePages: 11296768 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
Unaccepted:            0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      390716 kB
DirectMap2M:    20443136 kB
DirectMap1G:    12582912 kB

vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -------cpu-------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st gu
 3  0 7261148 505272 172672 26401488    1   38    46   344 1761    9 11  8 81  0  0  0

df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  3.7M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2   97G   40G   53G  43% /
tmpfs            16G  224M   16G   2% /dev/shm
efivarfs        192K   59K  129K  32% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
tmpfs           5.0M   16K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-udev-load-credentials.service
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2823
/dev/loop5      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop4      104M  104M     0 100% /snap/core/16928
/dev/loop2       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M   17M  495M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/loop6      105M  105M     0 100% /snap/core/17200
/dev/loop1      165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2829
tmpfs            16G   26M   16G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p4  183G  101G   73G  59% /home
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
tmpfs           3.2G  272K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-journald.service

sudo ps axo pid,rss,cmd | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^ //' | cut -d' ' -f2-3 | sort -rn | head -n 20
677376 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
437912 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
379600 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
267984 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
256164 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
250152 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
235232 /usr/share/spotify/spotify
234216 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
232516 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
224920 /usr/bin/gnome-software
220972 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
218780 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
214904 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
214520 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
214324 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
205100 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
201692 /usr/share/spotify/spotify
193748 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
191564 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
184612 /opt/google/chrome/chrome

sudo ps axo pid,rss,cmd | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^ //' | cut -d' ' -f2-3 | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
11938392

smem --system
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory      26490052   25694396     795656 
userspace memory            5750456     866412    4884044 
free memory                  494964     494964          0 


Reached 100%, chrome killed and now at 80%:
free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31968       26359        4858       23038       24317        5609
Swap:           7627        7625           2

cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       32735472 kB
MemFree:         4975152 kB
MemAvailable:    5743848 kB
Buffers:          126544 kB
Cached:         24489592 kB
SwapCached:        32272 kB
Active:         15207960 kB
Inactive:       10981032 kB
Active(anon):   14489572 kB
Inactive(anon): 10660116 kB
Active(file):     718388 kB
Inactive(file):   320916 kB
Unevictable:      615116 kB
Mlocked:             216 kB
SwapTotal:       7811068 kB
SwapFree:           2364 kB
Zswap:                 0 kB
Zswapped:              0 kB
Dirty:              9352 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       2155592 kB
Mapped:           342216 kB
Shmem:          23576784 kB
KReclaimable:     270204 kB
Slab:             533652 kB
SReclaimable:     270204 kB
SUnreclaim:       263448 kB
KernelStack:       17648 kB
PageTables:       105720 kB
SecPageTables:         0 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    24178804 kB
Committed_AS:   43450832 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       64300 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             9632 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    929792 kB
ShmemHugePages: 10631168 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
Unaccepted:            0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      390716 kB
DirectMap2M:    20443136 kB
DirectMap1G:    12582912 kB

vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -------cpu-------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st gu
 4  0 7808704 4983344 126544 24758628    1   39    52   346 1767    9 11  8 81  0  0  0

df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  3.7M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2   97G   40G   53G  43% /
tmpfs            16G   11M   16G   1% /dev/shm
efivarfs        192K   59K  129K  32% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
tmpfs           5.0M   16K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-udev-load-credentials.service
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2823
/dev/loop5      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop4      104M  104M     0 100% /snap/core/16928
/dev/loop2       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M   17M  495M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/loop6      105M  105M     0 100% /snap/core/17200
/dev/loop1      165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
/dev/loop3       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2829
tmpfs            16G   14M   16G   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p4  183G  101G   73G  59% /home
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
tmpfs           3.2G  264K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-journald.service

sudo ps axo pid,rss,cmd | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^ //' | cut -d' ' -f2-3 | sort -rn | head -n 20
434400 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
224408 /usr/bin/gnome-software
215492 /usr/share/spotify/spotify
214396 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
196668 /usr/share/spotify/spotify
178252 tmux
148600 /app/extra/anydesk
129872 node
102524 /home/susensio/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/python-lsp-server/venv/bin/python
84256 /usr/share/spotify/spotify
54616 /usr/share/spotify/spotify
47124 /usr/sbin/dockerd
45436 nvim
34244 /usr/bin/python3
33188 /usr/libexec/fwupd/fwupd
30652 /usr/bin/Xwayland
26152 nvim
22992 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-journald
22844 /usr/bin/containerd
21108 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd

sudo ps axo pid,rss,cmd | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^ //' | cut -d' ' -f2-3 | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
2991124

smem --system
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory      25234136   24548224     685912 
userspace memory            2527240     351560    2175680 
free memory                 4974096    4974096          0 


Fresh restart, 10% RAM usage
free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31968        3804       25956         957        3605       28163
Swap:           7627           0        7627

cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       32735468 kB
MemFree:        26579244 kB
MemAvailable:   28839260 kB
Buffers:          278844 kB
Cached:          3246332 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          3550176 kB
Inactive:        1132104 kB
Active(anon):    2137228 kB
Inactive(anon):        0 kB
Active(file):    1412948 kB
Inactive(file):  1132104 kB
Unevictable:      916424 kB
Mlocked:              96 kB
SwapTotal:       7811068 kB
SwapFree:        7811068 kB
Zswap:                 0 kB
Zswapped:              0 kB
Dirty:              2300 kB
Writeback:           272 kB
AnonPages:       2070276 kB
Mapped:           954168 kB
Shmem:            980108 kB
KReclaimable:     166528 kB
Slab:             316460 kB
SReclaimable:     166528 kB
SUnreclaim:       149932 kB
KernelStack:       18524 kB
PageTables:        46992 kB
SecPageTables:         0 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    24178800 kB
Committed_AS:   16034172 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       63888 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
Percpu:             8256 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    262144 kB
ShmemHugePages:   880640 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
FileHugePages:         0 kB
FilePmdMapped:         0 kB
Unaccepted:            0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB
DirectMap4k:      263740 kB
DirectMap2M:     5890048 kB
DirectMap1G:    27262976 kB

vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -------cpu-------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st gu
 5  0      0 26576736 278844 3412860    0    0 34640  2329 7573   23 23  7 68  2  0  0

df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  2.7M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2   97G   39G   54G  42% /
tmpfs            16G   36M   16G   1% /dev/shm
efivarfs        192K   59K  129K  32% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
tmpfs           5.0M   16K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-journald.service
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-udev-load-credentials.service
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service
/dev/nvme0n1p4  183G  101G   73G  59% /home
/dev/nvme0n1p1  511M   17M  495M   4% /boot/efi
/dev/loop6      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop0      165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/198
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2829
/dev/loop3      104M  104M     0 100% /snap/core/16928
/dev/loop1      105M  105M     0 100% /snap/core/17200
/dev/loop5       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2823
/dev/loop4       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
tmpfs            16G  2.5M   16G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           1.0M     0  1.0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
tmpfs           3.2G  196K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000

sudo ps axo pid,rss,cmd | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^ //' | cut -d' ' -f2-3 | sort -rn | head -n 20
390464 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
342408 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
328228 /usr/bin/gnome-software
307484 /usr/lib/insync/insync
175120 /usr/bin/wireplumber
158100 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
153760 /usr/bin/gnome-text-editor
142352 /usr/libexec/epiphany-search-provider
137072 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
133920 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
132476 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
121076 tmux
119420 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
118364 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
114332 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
112104 /usr/lib/insync/PySide2/Qt/libexec/QtWebEngineProcess
100300 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
85112 /usr/bin/python3
84188 node
81472 /usr/libexec/mutter-x11-frames

sudo ps axo pid,rss,cmd | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^ //' | cut -d' ' -f2-3 | awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
6240312

smem --system
Area                           Used      Cache   Noncache 
firmware/hardware                 0          0          0 
kernel image                      0          0          0 
kernel dynamic memory       3150692    2737536     413156 
userspace memory            3032536     954168    2078368 
free memory                26552240   26552240          0 


Update:
vmstat 1 3 on 30%
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -------cpu-------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st gu
 6  0   1024 19496368 238424 7531928    0    0   387   574 2971   16 20 12 68  1  0  0
18  0   1024 19509336 238424 7528512    0    0     0   608 2166 9096 16 14 70  0  0  0
 3  0   1024 19489420 238424 7537988    0    0     0   104 2546 14051 20 13 66  0  0  0

vmstat 1 3 on 65%
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -------cpu-------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st gu
 4  0   1024 8079324 287156 18145720    0    0   307   489 3005   16 20 12 67  1  0  0
 0  0   1024 8118796 287156 18134472    0    0     0    68 3739 19496 25 16 59  0  0  0
 0  0   1024 8101332 287156 18135472    0    0     0     0 3982 20654 22 16 62  0  0  0

vmstat 1 3 on 95%
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -------cpu-------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st gu
12  0 7678576 1114908 131684 26900496    6  167   601   412 1345   16 21 14 64  1  0  0
10  0 7678576 1291708 131684 26779548    0    0     0     0 3227 12078 24 15 61  0  0  0
21  0 7678576 1121060 131684 26937124    0    0 15928     4 4720 13898 30 17 52  1  0  0

vmstat 1 3 on 80%, after chrome has been killed
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -------cpu-------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st gu
24  0 6951568 6888104  34076 23076116    6  159   592   403 1342   16 21 14 64  1  0  0
17  0 6951568 6863232  34076 23083388    0    0  7300     0 2190 10313 18 15 67  0  0  0
21  0 6951568 6853228  34084 23084148    0    0     0    56 1965 10473 19 14 68  0  0  0

No amount of echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches fixes it.

When run vmstat use command like vmstat 1 3 and take the last line, because the first line are aggregated values from the start of the machine.

There you go: at low memory usage (30%)
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- -------cpu-------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st gu
 3  0   1024 19489420 238424 7537988    0    0     0   104 2546 14051 20 13 66  0  0  0`

Add this to the question, not as ccomment

It looks like your caches dont get freed ? Try manually resetting them through /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches and see if that helps temporarily.

no visible changes when echoing 3 to drop_caches

It seems that cache is filling up, I cannot bring it down, and my SO ends up killing other programs...

I've just noticed that Suspend frees it up
